# Godot 4.1 warning: Node 'NodeName' was modified from inside an instance, but it has vanished

Tags: godot-4

I've recently modified my `Enemy` class and removed some `Node`s from it. This `Enemy` class is like an abstract class: it's not supposed to be instantiated but all enemies inherit from it.

Now, when I instantiate an enemy, **sometimes** I get this warning:

```
W 0:00:01:0018   enemies_manager.gd:44 @ instance_enemy(): Node './DamageLabel' was modified from inside an instance, but it has vanished.
  <C++ Source>   scene/resources/packed_scene.cpp:182 @ instantiate()
  <Stack Trace>  enemies_manager.gd:44 @ instance_enemy()
                 enemies_manager.gd:93 @ spawn_enemy_pack()
                 enemies_manager.gd:116 @ spawn_random_enemy_pack()
                 enemies_manager.gd:26 @ _ready()
```

And when I mean sometimes, I really mean it! I press `F5` to run the project and it's fine, no warnings. Close the project's window, press `F5` again and **maybe it shows the warnings, maybe not**. It's like 50 / 50. **The game works correctly, with or without warnings**.

And no, the actual enemies that `extends Enemy` do not even try to access the deleted nodes. They are just a bunch of stats variables, sprites and death effects.

[Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=node%20was%20modified%20from%20inside%20an%20instance) this question gives one result to [ask.godotengine.org](https://ask.godotengine.org/32037/does-this-warning-mean-node-modified-inside-instance-vanished), but the website has been down from days now, so I don't know if it's solved there.

Anybody knows about this warning? Even if the game works, it's something that I don't like.

Edit: The project was started with Godot 4.0.3 and then upgraded to Godot 4.1, all stable versions.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what's happening without seeing more complete code for your project, or a minimal reproducible example.  I suspect this is something related to reparenting/removing a node or instantiating a scene.

Comment: I don't think I can make a minimal reproducible example for this case, sorry. What baffles me is the randomness of this: run the project, no warnings at all. Run again, warnings for every enemy instanced. The normal would be to have the warnings always or never.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the message, as the stack points out, it comes from `PackedScene` ([here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/851bc640ddf7225a4b52bb15cc50c249df119953/scene/resources/packed_scene.cpp#L182)):

> ```
> scene/resources/packed_scene.cpp:182 @ instantiate()
> ```

For what I've been able to gather this is a warning can happen with scene inheritance. In particular that the derived scene is trying to set some properties of a `Node` that no longer exists in the base scene.

That is:

- You had a base scene.
- You created a scene derived from it.
- In the derived scene you set some properties of `Node`s from the base scene in the editor (i.e. via the inspector). *I suppose it is possible that Godot might have erroneously saved the properties as if they were modified, as there were some related issues in the past.*
- You modified the base scene so that those `Node`s are no longer there.

And now when instantiating the derived class, Godot reads from the scene file that it has to set some properties of a `Node` it cannot find.

That is, the issue is that the derived scene file still have the reference to the `Node`s that are no longer available. In fact, you should get the same warning upon opening the derived scene in the editor. However, re-saving it should fix it.

Barring that, if you have a `tscn` file, you might try opening it with a text editor and try to find out which `Node`s it references that no longer exist in the base scene, and remove them.

---

<strike>I have no idea why you would get the message only *sometimes*. The first thing it suggests to me is that the situation depends on timing or load order (i.e. it is a race condition). However, that would imply some code manipulating the scene in unexpected ways (either before or while it is being instantiated). The fact that this coincided with upgrading to Godot 4.1 makes me wonder if it has anything to do with recent changes to scene threading. But that is all speculation.</strike>

Comment: This _"In the derived scene you set some properties of Nodes from the base scene in the editor (i.e. via the inspector)."_. I've revised all the enemies' scenes with vscode and find the culprit: One of the scenes retained a reference to an unexisting node that had it's properties modified in the inspector. Just opened the scene in godot and saved it. Warning fixed. And about the randomness; it has to do on how the enemies types are randomly spawned.